# iOS swift facebook login button is not showing up if i don't use classForCoder

Tags: ios, facebook, swift2, single-sign-on

I am trying to integrate Facebook single sign on to one of my iOS application. I have followed the instructions from Facebook and when i try to run the application i am getting the following error

```
Unknown class FBSDKLoginButton in Interface Builder file.
```

After searching on web, i found that adding the following code will resolve the issue.

```
FBSDKLoginButton.classForCoder()
```

My question is, what is the significant of this code? What does this perform behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/classForCoder):

`classForCoder` is a property `Overridden by subclasses to substitute a class other than its own during coding. (read-only)`

`This method is invoked by NSCoder. NSObject’s implementation returns the receiver’s class. The private subclasses of a class cluster substitute the name of their public superclass when being archived.`

*Declaration*:

```
var classForCoder: AnyClass { get }
```